# Mule 4 - Unable to override some of the values of HTTP Response headers

Tags: http-headers, mule, listener, mulesoft, mule4

I am facing difficulties in overriding the list of HTTP Response headers listed below

1. X-Content-Type-Options (from 1 to nosniff)
2. X-Frame-Options (from SAMEORIGIN to deny)
3. Set-Cookie (add HttpOnly;Secure)

I have tried to put these values into the Listener's HTTP Response headers as well as utilizing the Header Removal and Header Injection in the API Manager policies but to no success in overriding to the intended values.

May I know how do override the HTTP Response headers? Kindly refer to the photo of the values that I have set.

API Policies

[image: API policies]

Header Removal

[image: Header Removal]

Header Injection

[image: Header Injection]

Listener's response header values in the mule project

[image: listener header]

Response header from the API call

[image: response]

Comment: Is the Mule application deployed on prem, on CloudHub, or behind some load balancer? Try enabling HTTP wire logging to see the Actual output from the http Listener

Comment: Hi @aled, the Mule application is deployed to Cloudhub. Hmm, I will try to enable the HTTP wire logging and check the actual output first.

Comment: See https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging for instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These headers "X-Content-Type-Options", "X-Frame-Options" are injected by DLB, so not able to remove or modify at Mule app or policy level, unless not using DLB. MuleSoft has fixed it and should be available in their next release.

Comment: Yes @Lei Zhao, you are right,  I have managed to found out about this after struggling for quite some time. When you say MuleSoft has fixed it, does that means even DLB injected those headers but MuleSoft will allow us to remove or modify at the app or policy level in the next release?

Answer (score 0):

In the API Manager policies, use the Inbound Header Map instead of the Outbound Header Map for both header removal and injection.

Comment: Hi there @AndrWeisR, thanks for the answer, unfortunately, it is not working though